# View does not show over mapview

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

I am developing application which uses google map. I use the map to display a route and I want to show a View over the mapview when the route is drawn. While the route is drawing the View should not be visible. The problem is when the route is drawn and I set the view `VISIBLE` flag to true the view does not show over the map.

This is the layout I am using. As you can see the popup's initial state is `INVISIBLE`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/popup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/popup"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

For simplicity I will not post the whole java code but only part of the `onCreate` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // stuff that is not so important
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            /*
            The next line is the source of all evil. I use the sleep to simulate the
            time needed to draw the route. The problem is that if I wait for a while the
            map get initialized and when set the view to VISIBLE nothing happens - the
            view is not shown over the map. If I use 1 ms for sleep timeout the map is
            still not initialized and the view is shown correctly over the map.
            */
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        View view  = findViewById(R.id.popup);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    task.execute();
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: do you get any errors? does it work in debug? can you get the view to show the way you want if you set the visibility to true in the XML ?

Comment: No I do not get any errors. I am trying it only in debug for now and finally yes if I set the visibility to true in the xml is view is visible over the map. Furthermore if I set the visibility to true directly in the onCreate method(without waiting for the timeout) it is also working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overlay items then use FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout. The map is using `match_parent` which is taking up the whole screen and not allowing the view to appear. Try this,

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/popup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/popup"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is not in the parent layout. If the view is visible everything is ok so the parent layout is OK.